# Swift not allowing if statement because it dose not recognize an variable that is defined in the if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am trying to get the input of a text field so that if the user is the one that is allowed in then their user credentials can be matched to a folder that is in the cloud but swift is giving the error "expected declaration" but there is no variable that is undefined. if anyone can help me then that would be greatly appreciated.
[fist section of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClvlA.png) [second section of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuDi9.png)

Comment: Also, I forgot to add this but here is where username input and password input is defined {lazy var username_Input: String = UserName_TextField.text!}
    {lazy var password_Input: String = Password_TextField.text!}

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code from the full file?  At first glance it just looks like you have some basic Swift/iOS fundamentals missing, but it's really hard to tell what is happening without more context.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on in the second image (please post the code and the exact error message as text, not as an image), but in the first one, you just can't use `if` statements like that, they have to be inside a function/closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's giving you the expected declaration error in your first screenshot because your if statement is not in the body of a function. You have to put your if statement in the body of a function.

```
func checkUserCredentials(){
        if username_Input.text == "tyler" && password == ("1234"){

            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out I got it to stop giving me the declaration error. I am just working to get the user tag updated in another class but I will update this post when I have the fully working code.

Comment: Sweet. Glad to help.
What is the error you're getting in your second screenshot? Can you show us where you have "user" declared

Comment: I error that I was getting in my second screenshot was a declaration error because I had not declared the variable "user" and that was what I was trying to decare with the if statement (if user credentials match then set current user to x) but swift did not allow this because I was using the same variable across two different classes

Comment: @Monika_McByte So the if statement pretty much solves the problem in screenshot 2?